# Renaming file with Batch variable

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, rename

I have the following code:

```
set DATE=%date% 
echo %DATE% 
set DAY=%DATE:~0,2% 
echo %DAY% 
rename file09.txt file%DAY%09.txt
pause
```

It is supposed to rename a text file and put the day of the month in the file name. I am however getting a syntax error on the `rename` command.

I think the problem is in inserting the variable into the file name. Any help would be appreciated. The `echo`s are just in the program for my own reference.

Comment: Welcome to Batch (and its endless frustrations) **:)**  To start off what is the date format that you have set?  Also what is the exact error displayed?  Try placing quotations around your file names. "file09.txt"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As has already been stated - your code as pasted had trailing spaces on many lines and  the spaces often matter.  I posted this because you had reused the system DATE variable name and that causes issues, and to show you that quotes are often helpful - and needed with long filenames.

```
set "D=%date%"
echo "%D%"
set "DAY=%D:~0,2%"
echo "%DAY%"
rename "file09.txt" "file%DAY%09.txt"
pause
```

Comment: Thanks - didnt realise how important quotes are!

Answer (score 2):

you might have trailing spaces in the `set` command. Just try this:

```
set "DAY=%DATE:~0,2%"
```

btw. with `set DATE=%date%` you doesn't create a new variable. Variables must have case insensitive unique Names.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the date configuration, because of that the content of the variables is wrong.

Really use quotation marks worked as it ensures full name if the variables have spaces or unusual characters.

Review my post for view the Endoro answer..it works right for me

Renaming file with Batch variable doesnt work with another user profile
"[Renaming file with Batch variable doesnt work with another user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588902/renaming-file-with-batch-variable-doesnt-work-with-another-user-profile/19589213#19589213)"