# Renaming file with Batch variable doesnt work with another user profile

Tags: windows, batch-file, user-profile

I have a batch script that is using variables for rename a file. I'm developer and In my pc the script is working but in the production server with another user perfil, the "rename" doesn't work.  I probed with  another Administrator users but the script doesnt work either. I think it depends of some configuration in the user perfil, related with my Developer perfil that permit it works but i dont have any idea that what could be.

this is my script

> ========================================
>
> `@echo off`
> `ECHO GET FECHA`
>
> `set ano=%date:~6,4%`
>
> `set mes=%date:~3,2%`
>
> `set dia=%date:~0,2%`
>
> `echo Renombra file1`
>
> `rename file1 STATUS_%ano%_%mes%_%dia%`
>
> `========================================`

this is the error

> ```
> "The syntax of the command is incorrect."
> ```

this is the ok execution in my developer pc with my user

> ========================================
>
> C:\Users\pquiroza\Desktop>renombra
>
> GET FECHA
>
> Renombra file1
>
> C:\Users\pquiroza\Desktop
>
> ========================================

this is the wrong execution in the server, with the same program with my user or any other user

> ========================================
>
> C:\Users\pquiroza\Desktop>renombra
>
> GET FECHA
>
> Renombra file1
>
> The syntax of the command is incorrect.
>
> C:\Users\pquiroza\Desktop
>
> ========================================

Comment: Are the time settings the same? What is the output of `echo %ano%_%mes%_%dia%` on both machines/profiles?

Comment: check this topic for to get the date without worrying about time settings ; http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4555

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works for XP Prof. or better:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
for /f "skip=1delims=." %%a in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined DateTime set "DateTime=%%a"
ren file1 "STATUS_%DateTime:~0,4%_%DateTime:~4,2%_%DateTime:~6,2%"
```

Answer (score 2):

The `%date:~..%` stuff is probably locale-dependent, and might return different characters and formats when using different locales.

First thing I'd try quoting the arguments to RENAME, as it expects exactly 2 arguments for source and destination: `rename "file1" "STATUS_%ano%_%mes%_%dia%"`

Comment: Also use `if exist "file1"` in order to only rename it when it is there.